# Monsgeek Driver

Tags: keyboard, driver, custom-keyboard

I have a Monsgeek MW1.  I would like to know how to use the Monsgeek Driver to set the "e" key so that when I press ALT+e it returns: é.

I tried the following:

1. Open Monsgeek Driver > Main
2. Click on **E** key
3. In **combination**, click on **Alt**
4. In the dialogue box, I tried to enter é.  But I don't see how to do this.
   A. Cut and paste does not work.
   B. The keyboard icon next to the dialogue box has a very limited list of characters and **é** is not listed.

Comment: Are you on Windows? I believe the problem is the Windows keyboard layout, not the specific configuration in the Via software or similar. Your keyboard is most probably ANSI so you'd have to choose International ANSI or ANSI with dead keys. Sorry I don't have Windows to confirm the name

Comment: Yes, I'm using Windows.  As I understand it, Windows allows users to change their keyboard layouts via settings > Time & Language > Language & Region.  We can then select a language pack or go to our current keyboard select options and add a keyboard layout, arranged by language (not ANSI vs ISO).  I occasionally use accented letters.  My goal was to assign a key, not have to change language layout, type the key, and then have to change back.  It turns out that the Monsgeek driver just doesn't allow me to do that unlike VIA.  Thank you for your suggestion, though.